# How do I lookup the hire date of an employee based on sales rep field in NetSuite?

Tags: case, decode, lookup, netsuite

I am trying to create a commissions schedule that looks at the hire date and eliminates the eligibility of the employee if the ship date of that sale is before their hire date.
ie. Transaction search.  Formula (date) I need to compare the ship date and the hire date of the employee and filter out if hire date is after ship date. (simply put).

DECODE ({salesrep} , (CONCAT({employee.lastname}, {employee.firstname})) , {employee.hiredate})  **this does not work.**
CASE {salesrep} WHEN {employee.entityid} THEN {employee.hiredate} ELSE 0 END  **Nor does this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filtering records in a saved search by comparing two date fields, you can subtract one date from the other and compare the result to zero.

In your case, you can use:

Criteria tab -> Formula (Numeric) -> `{salesrep.hiredate} - {actualshipdate}` -> is less than or equal to -> 0